# Aggregate user defined function steps diagram in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I know that a Aggregate User Defined Function involves steps

- Initialize
- Accumulate(this step involves threading)
- Merge
- Terminate

Can anyone please suggest a diagram or a drawing like how does this look like?
I found some sort of example (map-reduce Paradigm) but I would like to generalize this to SQL terminology

[image]

So you would ask yourself Why I´d like to make a diagram. 
I have found the [msdn explanation about User Defined Aggregates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee842720.aspx)
they explain:

> A user-defined aggregate is used on top of a window specification to
>   aggregate over the events in that window and produce a single result
>   value. A UDA takes as its input a CEP window (that is the result of a
>   hopping, snapshot window, or count-based window operator) that
>   contains a set of CEP events and outputs a single return value (a CLR
>   type that maps to one of the StreamInsight primitive types). For more
>   information about windows, see Using Event Windows.
>
> You can implement UDAs that are more complex in their functionality,
>   than the simpler aggregates similar to count, sum, and average
>   provided by StreamInsight. One such example, computing time weighted
>   averages, is discussed in a later section.

But I am having problems on making a general drawing about it in SQL Server, searching more I found oracles:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you thinking of?

Comment: sorry I am using SQL Server 2008